# What server.xml is for in Java DB Web Starter GIT code?

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, devops

I've created a liberty bluemix project. Then bluemix created the GIT project. I've downloaded it in eclipse and now I want to enable more features.

There's a server.xml there

[image]

but no matter what features I add there, bluemix logs says I am still using the default ones.

I am just pushing the changes to GIT (so jazz will push them to bluemix)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding the server.xml from the starter is for your local Liberty runtime that you can also fire up from within the maven plugin. If you want to make changes to your bluemix Liberty feature set you can do so by setting cf environment variables.

See my recent blogpost on how I did this. 
https://bluemixdev.wordpress.com/2016/02/07/bootstrap-a-websphere-liberty-webapp/

I added the following to the build script in my deployment pipeline.

```
cf set-env blueair-web JBP_CONFIG_LIBERTY “app_archive: {features: [servlet-3.1]}”
cf push “${CF_APP}”
```

Alternatively you can set the liberty feature set within your manifest, see this blogpost on how to do so: https://bluemixdev.wordpress.com/2016/02/21/specify-liberty-app-featureset-in-manifest/

Answer (score 1):

If all you're trying to do is update the feature list, then setting the JBP_CONFIG_LIBERTY is the easiest way.

But if you're looking to provide more config in the server.xml then you'll need to provide a server package.

For example, for this case:
[image]

I can either:

- I  can issue a `cf push myBluemixApp` directly from the "videoServer" directory.
- Or, package the server using the `wlp/binserver package videoServer --include=usr` command and then push the resulting zip file `cf push myBluemixApp -p wlp/usr/servers/videoServer/videoServer.zip` https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/01/06/modify-liberty-server-xml-configurations-ibm-bluemix/
- Or, manually or using your build, create a wlp dir structure keeping only the files you want to upload as I've done in the `deploy` directory here: https://hub.jazz.net/project/rvennam/Microservices_Shipping/overview You can then push that directory as I'm doing (see manifest.yml). This will work with jazz/DevOps Services.

Packaging the server.xml within a war file is not the correct way.